# Authenticate to my website, from android, using Facebook

Tags: php, android, facebook

I've seen this in other apps, so I know it's possible.

I would like to use the native facebook system to offer as a first method of authentication.  The benefit of course is that most users are already logged into their facebook account on their phones, so they merely have to allow my app access and they're logged in... plus it's fairly portable to ios.

I understand how authenticate to facebook for the purpose of posting messages on user's wall and so forth, but I can't figure out how to use this authentication as a means of login on the http server.

Does anyone know of any write-ups on this?